# Is it possible to import a folder as a module?

Tags: python, import

I have a library I'm working on that is intended to be imported like `import raycekar as rk` and have its individual files referenced as `rk.unit.whatever`. This is the directory structure:

```
RayceKar
|-raycekar
| |-__init__.py
| |-ui.py
| |-env.py
`-main.py
```

From within `main.py`, if I `from raycekar import ui`, I can access `ui`. If I want to `import raycekar as rk`, `rk.ui` raises an AttributeError unless the from a import b variation is used first.

How can I make it such that accessing attributes as `rk.ui` or `rk.env` works without having to perform a `from raycekar import *`?

I'm working with Python 3.8+

Comment: You can have `from . import ui` in `raycekar.py`. But generally, I prefer to avoid hidden imports. Definitely ones with a wildcard, as your own suggestion. The `from . import ui` will at least keep the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you write in your `__init__.py` file?
For me it worked by writing this in my `__init__.py` file:

```
from .ui import *
from .env import *
```

But every additional file you add the `raycekar` directory you will have to manually import in your `__init__.py` just as shown before.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Worked a treat!